# Use RatingBar inside a custom renderer Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have this code, but I don't know how to add the RatingBar

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(RatingStars), typeof(RatingStarsRenderer))]
namespace MyStyle.Droid
{
public class RatingStarsRenderer : ProgressBarRenderer
{
    public RatingStarsRenderer()
    {
        RatingBar rb = new RatingBar(this.Context);
        rb.StepSize = 100;
        rb.NumStars = 5;
        rb.SecondaryProgress = 66;
    }

}
}
```

The RatingStars class is extending ProgressBar class.

Any help will be appreciated.

I am trying to add a RatingBar to my Xamarin.Forms project.

Comment: Can you please share some screenshots as to what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know how to display the control. So here it is:

```
SetNativeControl(theControl)
```